# SEARCH in multiple cells

Tags: google-sheets

The working formula i use, is:

```
 =IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($K$5;E3));"x";"")
```

In short, if K5 matches E3, a x is shown. How can i expand the searcharea to E3:F3?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want to show an X if E3 or F3 are equal to K5 then I would use =if(or(E3=K5,F3=K5),"x","")

The formula you provided does not verify if K5 matches E3 but looks for the value of K5 within E3. This means that with your current formula if E3 is 157 and K5 is 5 your formula would return an "x" because the 5 is contained in 157.